# table generator by buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with only one td, and I have two buttons one creates tr another td.
 The problem is that when I create tr, next td doesn't push in the last created tr.

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table)

var tr = document.createElement('tr');
table.appendChild(tr);

var td = document.createElement('td');
tr.appendChild(td);

var createTd = document.createElement('button');
createTd.innerHTML = 'Create td';
document.body.appendChild(createTd);

var createTr = document.createElement('button');
createTr.innerHTML = 'Create tr';
document.body.appendChild(createTr);

createTd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  tr.appendChild(td);
})

createTr.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
})
```

```css
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

You can try demo here : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rp4fwopb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your created `tr` is local and you add to the global `tr`.Just remove the var from the inner tr like this:

```
createTr.addEventListener('click',function() {
   tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
})
```

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anonmgnn/)

Answer (score 1):

you must set the new `tr`  to the global variable not to a local

```js
var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table)

var tr = document.createElement('tr');
table.appendChild(tr);

var td = document.createElement('td');
tr.appendChild(td);

var createTd = document.createElement('button');
createTd.innerHTML = 'Create td';
document.body.appendChild(createTd);

var createTr = document.createElement('button');
createTr.innerHTML = 'Create tr';
document.body.appendChild(createTr);

createTd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  tr.appendChild(td);
})

createTr.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(tr);
})
```

```css
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```